# Strange odor in home

Tags: cleaning

We have an unusual odor in our house. It doesn't smell like garbage, or anything rotten, just a sharp pungent smell as soon as you enter the house. It almost smells like stained wood that has got wet. We have log siding on the outside of our house, and all our baseboards and crown molding are wood that has been stained. We also have wood railings and doors. Could it be the stain that is on the wood making that smell? After a day we get used to it and don't notice it, but if we've been away a couple of days, we smell it as soon as we open the door. The house doesn't have a clean, fresh smell to it, even though I clean it often. Any ideas what it could be? Need help!

Comment: Can you locate the place where the smell is the strongest, or to put it in another words where the smell does comes from (which part of the room or at least which room) and then give us a pic or at least describe it.

Comment: It seems to be the whole house, but when you first walk in the door it's strong. Almost like a stinging burning feeling in your nostrils. I was away for a week, and noticed it right away when I came home. I get a lot of headaches and while I was away I didn't get any. After I was home for an hour I started getting a headache. I also suffer from a lot of nausea at home. Our house has a crawl space which is by the back door. The home was built in 2010 and the crawl space was built air tight with poly lining the bottom over the dirt. We have an HRV system and electric heat.

Comment: How often does your HRV operate?  What is the volume of the interior and ventilation rate of the HRV?  And have you made sure the HRV intake is clear of anything that might contribute to the odor?

Comment: Locating and identifying odors through the internet is nearly impossible.  You might want to contact a local HVAC company, home inspector, or somebody else whose able to do indoor air sampling.  They should be able to figure out what is in the air, and recommend ways to remove it.